# Click event on overlay image in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I work with canvas and I am using fabricjs.

I want to get a click event on overlay image in canvas using fabricjs.

Please help.

Comment: IS your overlay image spread-out over the whole canvas or on particular place only ?

Comment: @mayurkukadiya It's at the bottom-left of the canvas. I am using this syntax to set the overlay image: `canvas.setOverlayImage(image, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), { evented: true
      });`

Comment: can you post a working snippet or fiddle?